# Initializing a property through the private attribute

Tags: objective-c, initialization

I'm learning Objective-C with the Big Nerd Ranch Guide.
The author uses a store from which the controller can get some data to display :

```
#import "BNRItemStore.h"
#import "BNRItem.h"

@interface BNRItemStore ()

@property(nonatomic) NSMutableArray *privateItems;

@end

@implementation BNRItemStore

+(instancetype)sharedStore {
    static BNRItemStore *sharedStore = nil;

    if (!sharedStore){
        sharedStore = [[BNRItemStore alloc] initPrivate];
    }
    return sharedStore;
}

-(instancetype)initPrivate {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _privateItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

My question is about the `_privateItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` line : why do we initialize `_privateItems` and not `privateItems` ?

Regards.

Comment: Ron nailed it on the head. If you're looking for external references, see [Don’t Use Accessor Methods in Initializer Methods and dealloc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW6).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`privateItems` is the property name. Each property has a variable behind it, with a default name of `_propertyName`. in your case it's `_privateItems`.

Most times, you would use the property to set the value, like this: `self.privateItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]`. However, you should not set properties directly in `init` methods, and that is why the author sets the value directly to the variable.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Why is it not "doable" in the init method ?

Comment: It's *doable*, it's just not done. There are a couple of somewhat obscure pitfalls. The general rule is to manipulate ivars directly in `-init` and `-dealloc` because in `-init` the object might be only partially set up (due to inheritance) and in `-dealloc` the object might be partially torn down. The even-more-general way to say it is that you should not call any virtual methods (and all methods in Obj-C are virtual) on an object that could be either only partially constructed or already partially torn down.